# how to do when the cpu utiliztion makes high and need to launch a new server when cloudwatch alarm hits auto scaling group

Tags: aws-asg

if I launch an autoscaling group it automatically launches a certain instance that I have given in a desired capacity. And When the cloud watch alarm hits the instance should be launched through auto scaling.

if I launch an autoscaling group it automatically launches a certain instance that I have given in a desired capacity